# Multiple wars with cargo plugin

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, build, cargo-maven2-plugin

I am using such config in root POM.xml

```
<configuration>
    <deployables>
        <deployable>
            <artifactId>store</artifactId>
            <groupId>com.x</groupId>
            <type>war</type>
            <properties>
                <context>store</context>
            </properties>
        </deployable>
        <deployable>
            <artifactId>admin</artifactId>
            <groupId>com.y</groupId>
            <type>war</type>
            <properties>
                <context>admin</context>
            </properties>
        </deployable>
    </deployables>
</configuration>
```

But it leads to

> Artifact [com.x:store:war] is not a dependency of the project. -> [Help 1]

I even tried to include into this POM.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.y</groupId>
    <artifactId>admin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.x</groupId>
    <artifactId>store</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

How do I fix this issue?